# parsing file from ls -laLR

Tags: text-processing, sed, find, awk

```
ls -laLR /home/tools > all_site1.txt
```

I need the state of all folders and files in subfolders of `/home/tools`. With this command I put all in this file. What I need now is a solution how to parse from this file `all_sites1.txt` only lines where owner of dir or owner of the file is root.

I tried this:

```
awk '/root/{print $0}' all_sites1.txt
```

But I get all places where `root` occurs. I need only those entries where owner is root and what file and/or dir is to be printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to save the state of folders/files, `getfacl` is a much better command to use. You could do the following:

```
getfacl -LR /home/tools >all_site1.txt
```

One thing to note though is that the behaviour of the `-L` option is different from that of `ls`. It only follows symlinks to directories and not files.

You could print the output of files owned by root like this (provided none of the paths contain newlines):

```
awk '$2=="file:" && file_line=$0 {}
  $2=="owner:" && $3=="root" { print substr(file_line,9) }' \
  all_sites1.txt
```

Comment: Creating a pipeline from `awk` and `cut` is a bit strange, isn't it?

Comment: @Hauke Not really, `awk` has no support for selecting multiple arbitrary fields. Originally I had `cut -d ' ' -f 3-`, which replaces a complex `awk` line. `cut -b` isn't scuppered by leading whitespace in the filename though. But now that you mention it, I can just use substr in `awk`. So in this case, yes I guess it is strange.

Answer (score 2):

For reasonable file and directory names (not starting with space, no newlines) this works:

```
ls -laLR 2>/dev/null | 
    awk 'NF>8 && ($3 == "root" || $4 == "root") '\
    '{$1=""; $2=""; $3=""; $4=""; $5=""; $6=""; $7=""; $8=""; '\
    'sub("^ *",""); print;}'
```

As usual `find` is the better solution:

```
find . -user root -or -group root 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
shopt -s nullglob
stat -c%n:%U:%G * .*[!.]* ..?* | awk -F: '{if( $2=="root" || $3=="root")print $1}'
```

This will work on files in the current directory only.